# LotusNotes - Issue with view column field reference changing. Anyone experienced it?

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm not sure if this is a proper question, but it's been bugging me for quite some time now and I was hoping if anyone can share their experience on this issue.

Yesterday I created a view and already selected my desired fields for each column. I checked the sample data and was happy with the result. So I saved it and called it a day.

Then today when I came back to continue my work, I noticed that the 1st column's field, originally EmpID got changed to another field entirely, AppDate. At first, I thought that maybe I accidentally click something wrong to change it before I saved (although I'm certain that was not the case), so I change it back and test again. Only for the column to not change its data at all. Also I'm sure it wasn't a query formula issue, because I had it set as simple search, so that should be straight-forward.

I checked the column properties and in the Advanced tab the name does show EmpID, but the data displayed is still stuck on AppDate. So I tried selecting another field and hit refresh in my Design View, it changes to the new field no problem. And then I choose back EmpID, hit refresh again and it's back to how it was yesterday, back to normal.

This worries me because what would happen if the field change was not my error and it happens again when my program launches. Does anyone have faced this experience before and what are your fixes for this?

Answer (score 5):

I’ve seen it happen (ir)regularly: a programmatic name beginning with a $ sign sometimes remains unchanged.
Your column end up having the same programmatic name as another one in the same view, and will display that column’s content twice.
Easy to fix: just change the programmatic name to something unique.
Not a big deal. Always check you view after you built it.

Answer (score 0):

The name on the Advance Tab has nothing to do with the field that is displayed. That's just a way to give a column a name that's different from its title, so that column formulas can refer to each other by name.

Anyhow, in 26 years of working with Lotus Notes, I have never, ever seen a view formula change from referencing one field to another. I'm quite sure that you, or someone else, must have accidentally clicked on the AppDate, didn't notice it, and saved the change. It's quite easy to do.

Comment: That would be the case. But just before my lunch break, after I fixed it, it changed back again. I checked in Designer but it looked fine. But when I see it in Lotus Notes it has this issue. And this time I am 100% sure I did not touch a thing. My designer was closed at the time when it happened.

Comment: Is your db local or on a server ? Does your database inherit the design from another database and something trigged the design update ?